# Return other type variable than function's type

Tags: c++, arduino

How can I return variable with other type than function's type?

This is my code:

```
String wyslij(String cmd, boolean parse = false) {
  wifi.println(cmd);
  String response = "";
  bool beg = false;
  if(parse == true){
    (more code but this is not important)

    JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(response);

    return root; //how?

  }
return wifi.readString();
}
```

I would like to return "root", how can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: this looks like java why is it tagged as c++?

Comment: Soooo why can't you just change it to not return a String?

Comment: What is `JsonObject&`? It's not Java.

Comment: @bgarcia This is definitely not Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you can't. Making a union or a special struct just for passing around might give you what you want. Whether that's a good idea or not depends on what your caller is doing.

**Edit:** Here's one way:

```
String wyslij(String cmd, boolean parse = false, JsonObject * obj = NULL) {
  wifi.println(cmd);
  String response = "";
  bool beg = false;
  if(parse == true && obj != NULL){
    (*obj) = jsonBuffer.parseObject(response);
  }
  return wifi.readString();
}

void Caller() {
    JsonObject root;
    String ret_val = wyslij(cmd, true, &root);
    /* do things with root */
}
```

It may not work, depending on the side effects involved with making a `JsonObject` (among other things), but it'll give you the gist.

Comment: So, I would like to use "root" value outside the function - how can I do this? Maybe copy "root" value to another (public) variable?

Comment: There's a lot of ways to hold that object somewhere, or return it for use elsewhere. Copying it to a global will work, although it's a bad habit to get into. Returning a union or class (which you would define elsewhere) will work. Having a different function to do the parsing call that has a static `JsonObject` will work (sort of). Making it a string like bgarcia suggests would work if you just need a string. The way that makes the most sense will depend on the rest of your code and what this function is supposed to do in the first place.

Comment: Also, what does a function named `wyslij` do, anyway?

Comment: `wyslij` send a command to ESP8266, and when ESP8266 return json data I parse those data with ArduinoJson library (and now I would like to return this data outside function). When ESP return something else, it's return only `wifi.readString()`

Comment: "when ESP return something else..." the code you posted determines which type is returned in the method call rather than in the method body. there doesnt appear to be any reason to parse the response in the same method

Comment: If `wyslig` is meant to talk to the chip and tell you what the chip said, then it should do **only** that. You should do the parsing with whoever calls `wyslig`, not in `wyslig` itself. The correct answer is probably to not return `root` at all, and instead generate a `JsonObject` in the calling function.

Comment: Yet another way to "return `root`" would be to pass a reference to a `JsonObject` into the function and set the reference. That's probably closer to what you're after than any of the above, although I can't really recommend structuring the code this way.

Comment: What is `(*obj) = ...`? It's not Java.

Comment: @David Conrad: That is to de-reference the pointer. See the first example [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_passing_pointers_to_functions.htm).

Comment: @user2475059 The question says this is Java.

Comment: @David Conrad: It used to say C++, but someone who apparently doesn't know that Arduino has a capitalized `String` class in its libraries edited it to say Java. I don't have enough rep to unilaterally fix that, so my fix is stuck in review for now.

Comment: @user2475059 thank you so much! :) I will parse data in another function :) regards!

Answer (score 0):

you cant, it violates the language type system.

you should, however be able to get a string representation such as with root.toString() or an equivalent class method

Comment: So, I would like to use "root" value outside the function - how can I do this? Maybe copy "root" value to another (public) variable?

Comment: does it need to return String?

Comment: i would suggest parsing the response somewhere else rather than trying to do it in one method